# Capture API: Continously change focus to the center of the screen and adjust exposure automatically

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, material-ui, cosmicmind

I am using https://github.com/CosmicMind/Material specifically the Capture API, which was basically a simplified AVFoundation framework.

My goal was to have the app reset focus every time the screen moves, specifically focusing on what's in the center of the screen all the time even if not tapping the screen.

Focus currently can be changed while tapping.

Just using the capture api using

```
guard let capture = captureController?.capture else {
        return
    }
```

Comment: Whats the problem you're facing?

Comment: @Colwin I have no idea how to automatically set focus to center using the library.

Comment: As I can see from [`capture.swift`](https://github.com/CosmicMind/Material/blob/787aacb97687a7af3fea362b7ce0fc376fc3856a/Sources/iOS/Capture/Capture.swift) setting focus at the centre of the screen is not available for now. You might consider creating your own camera capture using `AVFoundation` to get what you needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the `open func focus(at point: CGPoint)` function ? I would disable focus on tap with setting `isTapToFocusEnabled` to false, and then programmatically setting the focus using the above mentioned function.